# How to automatically detect my display (monitor's) compatible settings?

Tags: monitor, settings

I changed my monitor recently and the settings the monitor expects is 1280X1024@60 Hz. Every time I restart my Ubuntu after a shutdown, the default setting that comes up for the monitor is 1280X1024@50Hz. As my new monitor is not compatible with this settings, it only displays the error message viz -  " The current input timining is not supported by the monitor display". The only way I can come out of this is, to connect an old monitor, change the settings to 1280X1024@60Hz and again reconnect the new one.

Can someone help me on how to make ubuntu automatically detect my new monitor's compatible settings when it boots up?

I am using Ubuntu 10.04

Thanks
Karthik

Comment: what graphics card do you use, which driver do you use? Maybe you can change the resolution / refresh rate parameters in /etc/X11/xorg.conf, if it exists on your system.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,